# create public key for RSA from base64 string

Tags: ios, swift, rsa

I'm using SWCrypt in swift 3. i'm get server public key in base64 string format. i should decrypt this JSON file with server public key.

```
{ "address":"asdf", "city": "asdf", "telephone": "345435", "zipCode": "1235458", "mobile":"3453245" }
```

in RSA decrypt and encrypt method public private key type is DATA, i try convert server public key to data but i can't encrypt data and get decode error.

there is my code for create public key and encrypt data.I'm get decode error for this code when try encrypt data.

```
 @IBAction func generateKey(_ sender: Any) {

    do {

    let (privateKey, publicKey) = try CC.RSA.generateKeyPair(2048)

    let privateKeyPEM = SwKeyConvert.PrivateKey.derToPKCS1PEM(privateKey)
    let publicKeyPEM = SwKeyConvert.PublicKey.derToPKCS8PEM(publicKey)

      privatePem = privateKeyPEM
      publicPem = publicKeyPEM

      print("this is generate public pem : \(publicPem!)")


    }
    catch {

      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

  }




  @IBAction func createDataOfServerKey(_ sender: Any) {


    var serverKey : String = self.serverKey.text!

    serverKey = serverKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2d", options: .literal, range: nil)
    serverKey  = serverKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "%2d", options: .literal, range: nil)


//    let datakey = NSData(base64Encoded: serverKey, options: .init(rawValue: 0))

    let dataKey = serverKey.data(using: .utf8)

    if let data = dataKey {

      serverKeyData = data
    }


  }


  @IBAction func encryptJson(_ sender: Any) {

    let json = jsonData.text

    let s = json!.data(using: .utf8)

    do {
    let encrypt =   try CC.RSA.encrypt(s!, derKey: serverKeyData!, tag: s!, padding: .pkcs1, digest: .md5)

      publicPem64.text = encrypt.base64EncodedString(options: [])

      print("this is encrypt json : \(publicPem64.text)")
      print(publicPem64.text.characters.count)
      view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    catch {

      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }



  }
```

this code working and return encryption data and when then i send this result base64string to server but i can't get any response.

```
@IBAction func createDataOfServerKey(_ sender: Any) {


    var serverKey : String = self.serverKey.text!


 let datakey = NSData(base64Encoded: serverKey, options: .init(rawValue: 0))


    if let data = dataKey {

      serverKeyData = data
    }


  }
```

in addition in android use un_wrap base64 decoding.

Comment: Why not just use HTTPS between the client and server?

Comment: @zaph for payment transaction we should use RSA for more security.

Comment: Asymmetric encryption such as RSA is not more secure than symmetric encryption such as AES. HTTPS used both asymmetric and symmetric encryption, the data is encrypted with symmetric encryption, generally AES. In geneeral keys are encrypted with asymmetric encryption and daqta is incrypted with symmetric encryption. If you are doin payments you need to be PCI compliant.

Comment: @zaph our back-end  team is using RSA and https, so I have to do what they are asking me. now i don'n know my problem in convert server key to data ? RSA encryption method or in my final base64 encoding...